# get email header and only selected text in outlook

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2007

I am using Office 2007 and Windows 7. With macro below, I extract text from email and open document in Chrome. But, what I want is not to extract whole text, but just selected text and the email header (To, CC, Subject). Is this possible ?

```
Sub OpenInBrowser()

    Dim BrowserLocation As String
    Dim AlwaysConvert As Boolean
    Dim EvaluateHTML As Boolean

    '=============Set your variables in the section below==========================
    'The default settings are optimized for viewing newsletters and receiving
    'messages with HTML forms or animated gif-files embedded in the message.

    'Set the location of the executable of the browser you want to use.
    BrowserLocation = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

    'When set to True, we will let Outlook convert the message to HTML.
    'The message will be opened in the configured browser just as it
    'appears in Outlook.
    'Standard value: False
    AlwaysConvert = False

    'When set to True, we will look for embedded resources in the HTML message and
    'determine whether Outlook should convert the message or whether we can strip
    'the HTML directly. When set to False, we will always strip the HTML and ignore
    'embedded resources.
    'For this setting to take effect, AlwaysConvert must be set to False.
    'Standard value: True
    EvaluateHTML = True

    '=======Don't modify the code below unless you know what you are doing=========

    'Get the user's TempFolder to store the item in
    Dim FSO As Object, TmpFolder As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set TempFolder = FSO.GetSpecialFolder(2)

    'Get all selected items
    Dim MyOlNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set MyOlNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set MyOlSelection = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    'Make sure at least one item is selected
    If MyOlSelection.Count = 0 Then
       Response = MsgBox("Please select an item first", vbExclamation, MyApplName)
       Exit Sub
    End If

    'Make sure only one item is selected
    If MyOlSelection.Count > 1 Then
       Response = MsgBox("Please select only one item", vbExclamation, MyApplName)
       Exit Sub
    End If

    'Retrieve the selected item
    Set MyselectedItem = MyOlSelection.Item(1)

    'construct the filename
    Dim FileName As String
    strname = "www_howto-outlook_com"
    FileName = TempFolder & "\" & strname & ".htm"

    'If the message is in HTML format we directly capture the HTML from the message
    'to construct our htm-file. This will allow us to capture as many HTML elements
    'as possible. If it is a different format, or if the HTML mail includes embedded
    'resources we let Outlook convert it to HTML.
    Dim OutlookConvert As Boolean
    OutlookConvert = True

    If MyselectedItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML And AlwaysConvert = False Then
        Dim rawHTML As String
        rawHTML = MyselectedItem.HTMLBody

        If EvaluateHTML = False Then
            OutlookConvert = False
        Else
            'Check if there are embedded resources in the message.
            'If it does, we let Outlook convert the message.
            If InStr(UCase(rawHTML), UCase("src=""cid:")) = 0 Then
                OutlookConvert = False
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'Write the temp-file
    If OutlookConvert = False Then
            'create the htm-file in the temp folder and write the HTML code to it
            Set objFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(FileName, True)
            objFile.Write "" & rawHTML
            objFile.Close
            Set objFile = Nothing
    Else
            'let Outlook convert the message and save the selected item
            'as htm to the temp folder
            MyselectedItem.SaveAs FileName, olHTML
    End If

    'open the saved item in the browser
    Shell BrowserLocation & " " & FileName, vbNormalFocus

    'Cleanup
    Set FSO = Nothing

    Set MyOlNamespace = Nothing
    Set MyOlSelection = Nothing
    Set MyselectedItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Edit:**

Here's my macro which extracts email header (From, To, Subject ...) and selected text in email - but selected text is raw text, without HTML.

```
Sub OpenInBrowser()

Dim BrowserLocation As String
Dim AlwaysConvert As Boolean
Dim EvaluateHTML As Boolean

'=============Set your variables in the section below==========================
'The default settings are optimized for viewing newsletters and receiving
'messages with HTML forms or animated gif-files embedded in the message.

'Set the location of the executable of the browser you want to use.
'Standard value: "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
BrowserLocation = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

'When set to True, we will let Outlook convert the message to HTML.
'The message will be opened in the configured browser just as it
'appears in Outlook.
'Standard value: False
AlwaysConvert = False

'When set to True, we will look for embedded resources in the HTML message and
'determine whether Outlook should convert the message or whether we can strip
'the HTML directly. When set to False, we will always strip the HTML and ignore
'embedded resources.
'For this setting to take effect, AlwaysConvert must be set to False.
'Standard value: True
EvaluateHTML = True

'=======Don't modify the code below unless you know what you are doing=========

'Get the user's TempFolder to store the item in
Dim FSO As Object, TmpFolder As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set TempFolder = FSO.GetSpecialFolder(2)

'Get all selected items
Dim MyOlNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Set MyOlNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set MyOlSelection = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

'Make sure at least one item is selected
If MyOlSelection.Count = 0 Then
   Response = MsgBox("Please select an item first", vbExclamation, MyApplName)
   Exit Sub
End If

'Make sure only one item is selected
If MyOlSelection.Count > 1 Then
   Response = MsgBox("Please select only one item", vbExclamation, MyApplName)
   Exit Sub
End If

'Retrieve the selected item
Set MyselectedItem = MyOlSelection.Item(1)

'construct the filename
Dim FileName As String
strname = "header_printing"
FileName = TempFolder & "\" & strname & ".htm"

'If the message is in HTML format we directly capture the HTML from the message
'to construct our htm-file. This will allow us to capture as many HTML elements
'as possible. If it is a different format, or if the HTML mail includes embedded
'resources we let Outlook convert it to HTML.
Dim OutlookConvert As Boolean
OutlookConvert = True 


 Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector
 Dim rng As String

 Set insp = Application.ActiveInspector

 If insp.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
 Set msg = insp.CurrentItem

 If insp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then ' outlook 2013
     Set hed = msg.GetInspector.WordEditor
     Set word = hed.Application
     rng = word.Selection.Text
 End If
 End If   

If MyselectedItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML And AlwaysConvert = False Then
    Dim rawHTML As String

    Dim textBody
    If rng = "" Or Len(rng) < 3 Then 'sometimes one letter is selected by it self
        textBody = MyselectedItem.HTMLBody
    Else
        textBody = rng
    End If

    'Email header - to, cc, bcc, subject and selected text from body
    rawHTML = "<b><font size=4>" & MyselectedItem.Subject & "</b><br/>" & _
    MyselectedItem.SenderName & " [" & MyselectedItem.SenderEmailAddress & "]" & "</font><br/>" & _
    "<b>Sent: </b>" & MyselectedItem.SentOn & "<br/>" & _
    "<b>From: </b>" & MyselectedItem.SenderName & " [" & MyselectedItem.SenderEmailAddress & "]<br/>" & _
    "<b>To: </b>" & MyselectedItem.To & "<br/>" & _
    "<b>Subject: </b>" & MyselectedItem.Subject & "<br/>" & _
    "<hr>" & _
    textBody

    If EvaluateHTML = False Then
        OutlookConvert = False
    Else
        'Check if there are embedded resources in the message.
        'If it does, we let Outlook convert the message.
        If InStr(UCase(rawHTML), UCase("src=""cid:")) = 0 Then
            OutlookConvert = False
        End If
    End If
End If

'Write the temp-file
If OutlookConvert = False Then
        'create the htm-file in the temp folder and write the HTML code to it
        Set objFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(FileName, True)

        objFile.Write "" & rawHTML
        objFile.Close
        Set objFile = Nothing
Else
        'let Outlook convert the message and save the selected item
        'as htm to the temp folder
        MyselectedItem.SaveAs FileName, olHTML
End If

'open the saved item in the browser
Shell BrowserLocation & " " & FileName, vbNormalFocus

'Cleanup
Set FSO = Nothing

Set MyOlNamespace = Nothing
Set MyOlSelection = Nothing
Set MyselectedItem = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: `MyselectedItem.HTMLBody` is a string.  With VBA you can extract any part of that string you may require.  `MyselectedItem.CC`, `MyselectedItem.To` and `MyselectedItem.Subject` are also strings which could be added to the beginning of your output file.

Comment: Can I extract selected text? And please post your comment as answer.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Outlook and the Visual Basic Editor.  Click F2 to display the Object Browser.  Scroll down the left hand list (Classes) to find and select MailItem.  The right hand list will display all the properties and methods of a MailItem.  Many, such as BCC, Body and CC, will be obvious others you will have to look up.

Click on CC. Underneath the two lists you will see: "Property **CC** As String".

You have not asked for Recipients but scroll down and select Recipients.  Now you will see "Property **Recipients** as Recipients" with the second "Recipients" underlined and coloured green.  You can click the second Recipients but I doubt you will find it helpful until you are more familiar with these properties.  Look up "Recipients" in Help and you will get an example of how to add a recipient.  To access the existing recipients you treat Recipients as an array (its actually a collection).

CC, To and Subject are all strings so are easy to access.

HtmlBody is a string so is easy to access (as you have) but it is an Html string with tags, attributes, element values and so on.  Extracting the particular text you seek may be a little challenging.  If you explain what you are after, I may be able to offer further help.

Comment: I want to print only selected text + header of email (Sent, To, From, Subject). So, I select some text, click on my macro and the browser window opens, with selected text only and email header. I have found the way to extract text and header. The only thing which is missing is extracted text is without html markup - it's raw text.

Comment: Where do you lose the html markup?  `MyselectedItem.HTMLBody` will contain markup.  I cannot see anything in your macro that would remove markup.  Is is possible you are using `MyselectedItem.Body` which will be raw text?

Comment: I know for HTMLBody property - it gives you whole email with HTML. This works. What I need is just selection of the text. And here all I can get is raw text. Which is OK but very often, HTML is included in text so it would be good having it. I am pasting my whole solution below.